# How to use kernal in ServiceStack version="4.0.36"

Tags: servicestack

I want to use StandardKernel object in my IOC container for that I downloaded “ServiceStack.ContainerAdapter.Ninject”. this Ninject is dependency with ServiceStack.Common (≤ 3.9.59) but I AM using the latest version of ServiceStack version="4.0.36".

Can anyone suggest me how to use kernel in ServiceStack version="4.0.36".

IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel

Answer (score 1):

According to the package's [nuGet page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.ContainerAdapter.Ninject) , this package has a dependency on ServiceStack 3.9.59 *and below*.  It doesn't appear to currently support the 4.x version of ServiceStack.

Looks like the code is [hosted on github](https://github.com/cshyjak/ServiceStack.ContainerAdapter.Ninject).  You could contact the author and ask him about supporting 4.x or you could fork it, make it compatible with 4.x and then submit a pull request.